# "I have completed my master degree and am a doctoral student"

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement

Do I have to worry about verb agreement in the following sentence?

> I have completed my master degree and am a doctoral student

Comment: You don't have to worry about it  because you have got it right.  Did you think 'am'   and 'have' are incompatible in some way?

Comment: Verbs have to agree with their subjects, not with other verbs.

Comment: Not a trivial question. This is obviously a subject deletion from the 'I have completed my [MA][,]  and I am a doctoral student.' This is unarguably grammatical. The question is, 'May the repeated subject be deleted from a coordinated second independent clause when the  tense changes?' The answer is _yes, but avoid confusing / clunky results_.

Comment: If it is grammatical, then "We have completed our master degrees and are doctoral students" should also be. Is it really? Sounds rather awkward.

Comment: @macraf, nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @macraf 'Grammatical' and 'something that would not benefit from rephrasing' are by no means exactly synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because after "and" your listener or reader could expect either a verb to agree with the subject or a past participle to agree with the auxiliary "have". Therefore, for clarity's sake, it would be better "I have completed my master degree and I am a doctoral student"

Comment: I think the sentence is perfectly clear as is. The verb *am* is not a past participle, so there's no possibility of confusion.

Comment: Without getting into the nitty gritty, we all know that sometimes we judge a sentence for how "it sounds", I think, considering also that in English whenever possible it's better to include the subject, that "I have completed my master's degree and I am a doctoral student" is clearer especially when being spoken,

Comment: It's not always better to include the subject (although I'm not going to argue about this sentence). Sometimes repeating the subject is a terrible idea.